# Create Announcment and associate it to a Week object if one doesnt already exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model called `Period`, it has a column called `start_date`. I also have a model called `Announcement` which belongs to `Period` and `Period` has_many to `Announcements`.

When I create an `Announcement` I want to associate it to a `Period`, but I first want to check if a `Period` record exists that matches the `announcements` `created_at` date. If the `Period` record does exist just add the `period_id` to the `Announcement`.

If it doesnt then create a `Period` record and add its `ID` to the `announcement`.

Here is the code I have for my two models so far

**Period model:**

```
class Period < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :announcements

  def self.find_or_create(date)
    start_date = date.beginning_of_week
    where(start_date: start_date).first || create_through_related(date)
  end

  def self.create_from_related(date)
    start_date = date.beginning_of_week
    create! do |period|
      period.start_date = date.start_date
      period.duration = 7
    end
  end
end
```

Announcement mode:

```
class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :period
end
```

Comment: One thing to clarify - at which point you want his association to happen. After saving the announcement?

Comment: Well ideally I would like the announcement to be saved with a week_id. So Im guessing the logic for finding_or_creating a week needs to happened before.

However, I need the `created_at` date from the announcement to calculate whether a week exists or not.

It's a bit chicken or egg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A before filter?

```
class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :period

  before_create :assoc_period

  private

    def assoc_period
      self.period = Period.find_or_create(self.created_at)
    end
end
```

Comment: That does look like it would work but what would self.created_at be?

Comment: created_at? "I first want to check if a Period record exists that matches the announcements created_at date"

Comment: So that would get the announcements created_at date that I just would of just sent off to be saved?

Comment: Oh yeah, how about Date.today.beginning_of_week?

Comment: Also, could I move that `assoc_period` out into somewehre where it would be acessible to all other models

Comment: Yeah, you could put it in a module http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module/Concerning.html

Comment: Yeah when I create the Period I want the start_date to be the beginning of the week. So could I do 

self.period = Period.find_or_create(self.created_at.beginning_of_week, start_date: Date.today.beginning_of_week, duration: 7)

Comment: You're going to need to update your find_or_create method.  I suggest you write some specs and give it a shot dude ;)

Comment: Is there a solid chance I could just use the built in find_or_create_by that is built into rails to condense my code a bit. But yes i think your right i need to just give it a shot now, thanks for your help.

Comment: I forgot to ask but once that before_save code runs how do I add week_id to the period